# How do I distribute a Visual Studio template pack?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I have a Visual Studio project that I would like to distribute as a template to other developers across the organization. I've been able to package the project into a NuGet package, but I'm a bit lost on how to distribute this across the organization.

At this point, I'm considering copying the NuGet package to a shared location and setting up a process that'll run when developers sign in to install the package via `dotnet new -i <path_to_nuget_package_file>` but I suspect there may be a better way to accomplish this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In the past, I've done the same by building a Visual Studio plugin with all the templates packed in. Then, it's just a matter of copying the .vsix file to some shared location and all others just installing it once from there.

Comment: Interesting. When you would update the .vsix, would they just download the new version from the shared location and install the update that way?

Comment: Yes, it's all handled by the Visual Studio Extension installer. The only thing you need to watch out is to increase the version number. The contents change accordingly afterwards, just like any other plugin.

Comment: Awesome. I'll move forward with the same approach you used and keep an eye out for other alternatives. Thanks!